# question regarding symbolic expression for differential equations to an initial value problem

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am currently studying differential equation now, and I just have one question about the symbolic expression for an initial value problem. 
I don't quite understand what does sympolic expression mean, any explanation or help would be really appreciated.

[here is the image of this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6e4h.png)

Comment: I assume it means writing $x$ as a function of $t$? What do you think it means?

Comment: The word should be "symbolic". The "p" is a typo. What they want is for you to write $x = Qe^{At}$, for some $Q$ and then find the value of $Q$ that will give $x(0) = [-1, 3]^T$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!